# Does SharePoint listitem have a tag or hash to identify if the version still persists?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I'm having a problem with multiple people modifying the same item at the same time. In my event receiver (ItemUpdating) I'm taking some of the data and I write it to a separate sql.

If a saving clonflict occurs the data is written to sql, but only the changes in SharePoint from the first person will be stored.

Is there a hash, tag, metainformation associated with a ticket which I can check if the version in the event receiver is still equal to the one on the server? Before I write data to the external sql I want to make sure there will be not saving clonflict after ItemUpdating is ran.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe try to use the ItemUpdated event instead of ItemUpdating?

Comment: I really wanted to use the "old value - new value" possibilites within Updating, but to be sure saving was possible, I might have to implement that in another way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I **think** what you are looking for is the **eTag**.
Karine Bosch has a nice article here:
https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/improving-performance-of-sharepoint-sites/part-13-etag-header/

(According to stackoverflow's guidelines I should re-write her article here, but I could not possibly write it in a better way!)

Comment: I couldn't verify the property on SharePoint 2019. Since it's a very old article, something might have changed since.

Comment: I made an assumption that you are working on a library. It is an SPFile property and it is still there. It is not avaiable for the SPListItem object though.